# Specific formulation of a Laurent Series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, contour-integration, laurent-series

I'm rather new to this branch of calculus, but I've been trying to learn about it on my own time. I currently rather fluently understand more basic topics such as Taylor Series, which come with an easy little formula for determining them$\left(T_a(f(x))=\sum_{k\geq0}\frac{f^k(a)}{k!}(x-a)^k\right)$.
This is how I currently go about finding a Laurent Series, and I'm pretty sure it's wrong. Let's look at the example $$f(z)=\frac{1}{z+2}=-\frac1{x_1}=\frac1{x_2}:x_1=-(z+2)\wedge x_2=(z+2)$$ Basically, using these x-substituted forms, I take two Taylor Series combined to get one who has indices on $(-\infty,\infty)$. So:
$$-\frac1{x_1}=-x_1^{-1}=-T_1(x_1^{-1})=-\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^k(x_1-1)^{k-1}=\sum_{k=0}^{-\infty}(-1)^k(x_1-1)^{k+1}\\
\frac1{x_2}=x_2^{-1}=T_1(x_2^{-1})=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^k(x_2-1)^{k-1}\\
\therefore \sum_{k=0}^{-\infty}(-1)^k(x_1-1)^{k+1}+\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^k(x_2-1)^{k-1}\\
\downarrow\text{substituting }x_1, x_2 \downarrow\\\sum_{k=0}^{-\infty}(-1)^k(-z-3)^{k+1}+\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^k(z+1)^{k-1}\\
\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}2(-1)^k(-z-3)^{k+1}+(z+1)^{k-1}
$$
So yeah, even assuming this is the right sum equation, I'm still hella confused. Firstly, my end goal with understanding Laurent series is being able to calculate contour integrals, which you must use the coefficient of the $-1^{\text{st}}$ index of the series to calculate the residue$\left(\oint_{\gamma} f(z) dz=2\pi i\sum_{k\leq n}\text{Res}\left(f\left(z\right),z_k\right)\right)$. If someone could help explain to me what the correct way to calculate this is in the context of Taylor Series or introductory complex analysis terminology, that would be awesome. Thanks in advance!

Comment: if $f(z) = \frac{1}{z-a}$ then the geometric series is enough for finding its Taylor series around $z= z_0$. For more complicated functions, for example $f(z) = e^{1/z}\sin(z)$ around $z=0$, you'll need to expand $e^{1/z}$ and $\sin(z)$  as Laurent series around $z = 0$ (where $e^{1/z} = \sum_{k \ge 0} \frac{z^{-k}}{k!}$) and rearrange the obtained product, using the absolute convergence for justifying the reordering.

Comment: True as that may be, I'm using the laurent series to find its coefficient - not for the traditional use of replicating the function. I simply need the coefficient of the -1st term; geometric series and taylor series lack that for all functions.

Comment: I don't understand: why,what for and how you write $\;\frac1{z+2}=-\frac1{x_1}\;$ ? The rest was just beyond my understanding . And **where**, or in what domain, do you want to develop the Laurent series of that function?

Comment: I'm trying to develop the series at $z=1$, I think. Again, this is in the context of trying to find the complex residue of the function at its singularity, $z=-2$. I used a substitution via $x_1$ to be able to write the Taylor Series for the same function, but with a negation such that I can index it within $(-\infty ,0]$